# Let $ \ f: [1,\infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty) $ be a continuous , decreasing function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $ \ f: [1,\infty) \rightarrow (0, \infty) $ be a continuous , decreasing function such that $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f(x)=0$ . Let us denote $ \ S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) , \ \ I_{n}=\int_{1}^{n} f(t) dt  \ \ and \ \  d_{n}=S_{n}- I_{n} $. Then show that $ \ 0 \leq f(n) \leq d_{n} \leq f(1). $ $$ $$ I see that $ |S_{n} -I_{n}| \rightarrow 0 $  . Then how to prove , please help me

Comment: yes , it was my mistake

Comment: Also not $|S_n-I_n|\to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe from the fact that $f$ is decreasing that $$f(k)=\int_k^{k+1}f(k)\,\mathrm dt\ge \int_k^{k+1}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\ge \int_k^{k+1}f(k)\,\mathrm dt=f(k+1).$$
By summing the instances of this inequality for $k=1,\ldots, n-1$, we obtain
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)\ge\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\ge\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k+1)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}f(k)$$
or
$$ S_{n}-f(n)\ge I_n\ge S_n-f(1),$$
hence 
$$ f(n)\le S_n-I_n\le f(1).$$

Comment: Ok , I have shown  the above inequality. This proves $ 0 \leq f(n) \leq f(1) $  , but we need to prove extra more